# Find error in assembly code to find maximum and minimum values using conditional jumps

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I have tried to write an assembly code to find maximum and minimum value and store them in AX and BX respectively from an array of 15 numbers, but when compiled the minimum value is correct but maximum is not correct.
here is the code and screenshot of result is also attached, kindly someone correct me.

```
[org 0x0100] 

jmp start
num: dw 16,40,48,30,10,3,4,7,44,32,23,34,43,50,54
start: mov bx, [num] 
mov ax, [num]
mov si,2
abc: cmp [num+si], bx
jnc skip
mov bx,[num+si]
skip: add si,2 
cmp si,30 
jnz abc 
mov si,2
xyz: cmp ax,[num+si] 
jnc skip1 
mov ax,[num+si] 
skip1: add si,2 
cmp si,30 
jnz xyz 
mov ax, 0x4c00 
int 0x21
```

[image]

Comment: Comment your code, especially if you want others to help. Also, learn to use a debugger to step through the code so you can find the error yourself.

Comment: The maximum on the screenshot is `ax = 0036` which is `0x36 = 54` and `54` is the maximum value in your array, i.e. it works well? What is not correct?  (Although I would have quite some comment to the code itself, how to write it in more readable and logical way (using `jnc` for both min/max compares is inducing pointless strain on the reader, to notice the argument order swapped, etc...) ... but it should work correctly, also from the screenshot it looks to be working correctly).